Chainlink SPL Token swap
Hallo liebe Community,
Ich hoffe, es geht dir gut? Ich habe eine Frage, nämlich, dass ich kürzlich in meinem Trust Wallet SOL gegen Chainlink SPL getauscht habe, weil ich Chainlink besser versenden kann, weil das Solana-Netzwerk keine guten Transaktionen über Trust Wallet durchführt.
Alles schön und gut, meine Chainlink- und meine Solana-Tokens wurden dann zu Chainlink SPL-Tokens zusammengeführt. Als ich dann mein Chainlink auf ein anderes Wallet verschoben habe, ist mir aufgefallen, dass der gesendete Betrag in meinem Trust Wallet immer noch als „Chainlink SLP“ angezeigt wird. Außerdem kann ich meine Solana-Tokens nicht mehr von Chainlink SPL in normales Solana umwandeln? Habe ich meine Solana-Tokens verloren und warum sind die gesendeten Links immer noch in meinem Trust Wallet zu sehen, obwohl sie schon längst auf dem anderen Wallet angekommen sind? Ich hoffe, jemand kann mir helfen. Herzliche Grüße und vielen Dank im Voraus

I’m voting to close this question because it's not in English
